# Can you use a.b notation in a #define macro name?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I want to declare a define, using Visual Studio 2008 or 2010, like that:

```
#define a.b c.d
```

and I get following error:

> error C2008: '.' : unexpected in macro definition

I see that I am allowed to create a define like this:

```
#define a c.d
```

Is the `a.b` notation supposed to be allowed in the macro name?

Comment: If you are using C++ do not use macros unless absolutely necessary - C++ gives you better mechanisms

Comment: Please add some scope or environment in which your `#define` will be used.

Comment: You're lucky that MSVS is correct telling you it is an invalid macro definition. In C89, it would be possible to argue that the identifier of the macro is `a` and the replacement text starts with the first `.`. GCC says `warning: missing whitespace after the macro name`. However, §6.10.3 ¶3 of the ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard says 'There shall be white-space between the identifier and the replacement list in the definition of an object-like macro' (C99 is similar; C89 does not state that). So, GCC is lenient: it gives a diagnostic warning, which is all that is required of a compliant compiler.

Answer (score 13):

Macros has same set of rules for naming, as do identifiers. In fact, macro-names *are* identifiers.

So,

- They **cannot** contain dot.
- They **can** consist of only alphabet, digits, and underscore. Nothing else. They **cannot** *start* with a digit, however.

Comment: I understand that, but it is a way to avoid this rule ?

Comment: @SerbanLupu Not unless you want to create your own preprocessor to go through your code before you send it to the compiler.  It is a rule after all.

Answer (score 3):

How about doing the follwing instead?

```
#define a c
#define b d
```

Comment: I want to map 2 structures of other and this define doesn't help me.