# C enum-like preprocessor define with dot access to "fields"?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I guess, what I want is something similar to this posting for C++ [Accessing to enum values by '::' in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090949/accessing-to-enum-values-by-in-c) :

> I want to: ... access Color values as `Color::Red`.
>
> ---
>
> In current C++ (i.e. C++11 and beyond), you can already access enum values like that:
>
> ```
> enum Color { Red };
> Color c = Color::Red;
> ```

So, I would like to know - can I do a similar level of access in C, but through a define (so I don't have to create an extra variable)? For example, say I have this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int model_type = 1;
int model_variant = 4;

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World %d\n", model_variant);
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to write something like this instead:

```
int model_type = DEFAULT.MODEL_TYPE;
int model_variant = DEFAULT.MODEL_VARIANT;
```

I'm aware that macro names (via [Can you use a.b notation in a #define macro name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040391/can-you-use-a-b-notation-in-a-define-macro-name)):

> They *cannot* contain dot.

... but I'd still like to know - is there maybe some sort of a trick, so I can I achieve something like this (being able to access a numeric value via say DEFAULT.MODEL_TYPE) on the preprocessor level in C? I'd like the preprocessor, since it will just insert raw numbers where needed - otherwise I have to define a struct, then a variable of that struct type, then populate that variable ...

If not, are there other options for similar typing style - say accessing enum fields directly by name? (I've tried `enum DEFAULTS { MODEL_TYPE =1, MODEL_VARIANT = 4 };`, but `DEFAULTS` then is "undeclared identifier", and as such, `DEFAULT.MODEL_TYPE` won't work either - so in that sense, I cannot use it for my purpose) ...

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that, but perhaps someone else can come up with something. An alternative might be to include the name in the enumeration constants, for example `enum Color { Color_Red, Color_Green, Color_Blue };`. Would that satisfy your requirements?

Comment: I don't think you can do anything with the dot using the preprocessor. A different syntax could be possible, like `DEFAULT(MODEL_TYPE)`, or maybe `ENUM(DEFAULT, MODEL_TYPE)`.

Comment: If you are OK with preprocessor solution, you can have something like `MODEL_TYPE(DEFAULT)` to expand into a prefefined  `DEFAULT_MODEL_TYPE`. Not sure what the benefit of it though.

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't want to program in C.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all - good to have it confirmed that dot cannot be used in this sense; and thanks for the alternatives, very good to have an overview of what my options are here!

Comment: A global `struct something DEFAULT;` with members `MODEL_TYPE` etc initialized to the appropriate values would give the dot syntax, but it's uglier than the problem it's trying to resolve ;-)

Comment: @dxiv it wouldn't work for static initialization

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I had to guess I would say that the OP has to integrate a C++ish code into a C project and is trying to mimimize changes/macroconditioning.

Comment: @PSkocik That's a fair point, and making it const wouldn't work in C either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object . foo` in C means (approximately) "add an offset (associated with `foo`) to `(char*)&object` cast the result to a pointer to the type associated with `foo` and then dereference".

Unlike in object-oriented programming languages, C's `.`/`->` is not an operator for accessing things *somehow* associated with an object.

If you don't want to be adding offsets to addresses of lvalues, you should be grouping things together differently, e.g., via a common prefix:

```
enum DEFAULTS { DEFAULTS__MODEL_TYPE =1, DEFAULTS__MODEL_VARIANT = 4 };
```

Comment: `__` makes those names reserved sadly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In C++ yes. In plain C no, unless the `__` is at the beginning of a name.

Comment: Huh, didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks - accepted this, as it explains also a bit more on how the dot access in C works (I had intuitively had that understanding too, but thought I could somehow avoid thinking about memory allocation and offsets via defines).

Comment: Right. Scoping in C is done with underscores. However, the double underscore is rather hard to distinguish from the single underscore. I have quite good experience with mixing underscore scoping with CamelCase: In this case, I would used something like `defaults_modelType` and `defaults_modelVariant`, making it clear that `defaults` is the scope, and that `modelType` is a name within that scope. Of course, that's incompatible with the tradition of using `SHOUT_CASE` for preprocessor macros. I, for one, prefer clear scoping over using shout-case, which I never liked anyways.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I don't use shoutcase either, but I do find it useful for comptime constants and  inlinables to be lexically distinct from regular variables/functions because of how they affect codegen compared to their regular counterparts. I use a custom suffix to communicate that (_$) and my editor recognizes such names, but that's just what I do. Shoutcase is what's become the idiom for this in C.